# Default Event calendar view is missing

Tags: datetime

I have installed event calendar module and using Zen sub-theme.As event calendar module gives its own content type and view.I can see the content type however I am not able to find the default view Event Calendar in view list.Anybody know the reason please revert.

Answer (score 0):

It is made available as a view template.

Goto `admin/structure/views/add-template` and create a new calendar view based on the Date Field that you want to use.

Comment: But it comes by default as mentioned... Den Why to add by template?